# Symfony doctrine::build task cannot create table named order

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I have a database with a table named `order`.
When i run `php symfony doctrine:build --all`, i got the folowing error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'order (id BIGINT
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, status VARCHAR(255),
>   colissimonumber VARCHAR(25' at line 1.
>   Failing Query: "CREATE TABLE order (id
>   BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, status
>   VARCHAR(255), colissimonumber
>   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at
>   DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME
>   NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE =
>   MyISAM".

The problem is clearly that order has no backquotes arount it (if i run manually the query in phpmyadmin with backquotes, it works)

How do i tell doctrine to add backquotes around table and field names? Any workaround exept renaming my table ?

I run symfony 1.4.9 with doctrine 1.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn on `Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUOTE_IDENTIFIER` in your doctrine configuration mthod on `projectConfiguration` which will quote tables and col names but its not recommended:

> Just because you CAN use delimited
>   identifiers, it doesn't mean you
>   SHOULD use them. In general, they end
>   up causing way more problems than they
>   solve. Anyway, it may be necessary
>   when you have a reserved word as a
>   field name (in this case, we suggest
>   you to change it, if you can).

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/configuration/en#identifier-quoting

Comment: On a sidenote, you can also do that in databases.yml: attributes: { quote_identifier: true }

Answer (score 3):

You probably want your model to be named Order, but this doesn't mean that the corresponding RDBMS table must be named the same.

```
Order:
  tableName: project_order
  columns: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Got similar error when upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0. [`RANK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) is a function added in MySQL 8.0 whereas one of the table in our database has `rank` as column name.

My Setup:

```
- Symfony 1.5
- Doctrine 1.2
- PHP 7.4.24
- MySQL 8.0.27
- Ubuntu 20.04.1
```

Here are three possible solutions.

**[Solution 1](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/07-Databases):** Add `quote_identifier: true` in `config/databases.yml` file. Also, clear cache after change in configuration with `php symfony cc` or `php symfony cache:clear`.

```
all:
  doctrine:
    param:
      attributes:
        quote_identifier: true
```

**[Solution 2](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#identifier-quoting)**: Turn on `Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUOTE_IDENTIFIER` in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` file on `configureDoctrine()` method.

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$conn->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUOTE_IDENTIFIER, true);
```

**[Solution 3](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#identifier-quoting)**: Turn on `Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUOTE_IDENTIFIER` on specific table(s) which are potentially breaking the system.

```
$table = Doctrine_Core::getTable('table_name');
$table->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUOTE_IDENTIFIER, true);
```

---

Note: [From Doctrine 1 docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#identifier-quoting)

> Just because you CAN use delimited identifiers, it doesn't mean you
> SHOULD use them. In general, they end up causing way more problems
> than they solve. Anyway, it may be necessary when you have a reserved
> word as a field name (in this case, we suggest you to change it, if
> you can).